# How can return identity column value from table and insert other table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm beginner in SQL Server and in my database I have two tables:

- Table 1 with an id type `bigint identity(1, 1)`
- Table 2 with the columns name and `table1ID`.

I want to insert (into table 1) and generate an id value. Then I will insert that id value into `table1ID` of table 2.

i change table to this and write this query:

```
insert into Interconnect_Traffic_Analysis_MAIN   (Code_Op,Name_Op,Shomare_Tel,Duration,table1ID>>table1 id must save in this column) 
select  t7,t8,t9,t10 from Interconnect_Traffic_Analysis_Temp;
```

But how can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- declare a variable to hold your newly created IDENTITY value
DECLARE @Identity BIGINT

-- insert your values into the first table
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(list-of-columns)
VALUES(list-of-values);

-- get the newly generated IDENTITY value into your variable
SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- use that variable in your second INSERT
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(table1Id)
VALUES(@Identity)
```

**Update:**

With your updated question with the `INSERT` statement, use this code to include the `@Identity` value:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Interconnect_Traffic_Analysis_MAIN(Code_Op, Name_Op, Shomare_Tel, Duration, table1ID) 
   SELECT 
       t7, t8, t9, t10, @Identity 
   FROM
       Interconnect_Traffic_Analysis_Temp;
```

Comment: thanks for answering,i change my table 2,please review my question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
insert into TableOne values ('abc');
insert into tableTwo values ((select SCOPE_IDENTITY()));
```

`select SCOPE_IDENTITY()` goes give you the last inserted id.

See this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/446bc8/12)

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@Identity`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)